# encountered ReferenceError: dimple is not defined in the chrome console

Tags: meteor, dimple.js

i created a project loaded up d3 & dimple packages then run mrt:

```
$ meteor create chartapp
$ cd chartapp
$ mrt add d3
$ mrt add dimple
$ mrt
```

tested d3 presence on the browser console by typing:

> > d3

```
Object {version: "3.1.4", ascending: function, descending: function, min: function, max: function…}
```

but dimple seems to fail:

> > dimple

```
ReferenceError: dimple is not defined
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`dimple` package appears to be outdated, it doesn't export the `dimple` object with `api.export` in `package.js` file. You can either:

- Fork the package, fix that problem and then use your fork (plus make a pull request to the original creator)
- Leave the package for now and just copy the files from `dimple` library directly to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the package and updated it to use latest dimple.js v1.1.5 and released to atmosphere. Please check it out.

Comment: still happens at version 2.1.6